# Capture Ruby Logger output for testing

Tags: ruby, logging, minitest

I have a ruby class like this:

```
require 'logger'
class T
  def do_something
    log = Logger.new(STDERR)
    log.info("Here is an info message")
  end
end
```

And a test script line this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

gem "minitest"
require 'minitest/autorun'

require_relative 't'

class TestMailProcessorClasses < Minitest::Test
  def test_it
    me = T.new

    out, err = capture_io do
      me.do_something
    end

    puts "Out is '#{out}'"
    puts "err is '#{err}'"
  end
end
```

When I run this test, both out and err are empty strings.  I see the message printed on stderr (on the terminal).  Is there a way to make Logger and capture_io to play nicely together?

I'm in a straight Ruby environment, not Ruby on Rails.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392292/how-can-i-test-logger-messages-with-minitest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic is to use capture_subprocess_io

```
 out, err = capture_subprocess_io do
     do_stuff
 end
```

Answer (score 5):

MiniTest's `#capture_io` temporarily switches `$stdout` and `$stderr` for `StringIO` objects to capture output written to `$stdout` or `$stderr`. But `Logger` has its own reference to the original standard error stream, which it will write to happily. I think you can consider this a bug or at least a limitation of MiniTest's `#capture_io`.

In your case, you're creating the `Logger` inside the block to `#capture_io` with the argument `STDERR`. `STDERR` still points to the original standard error stream, which is why it doesn't work as expected.

Changing `STDERR` to `$stderr` (which at that points *does* point to a `StringIO` object) works around this problem, but only if the Logger is actually created in the `#capture_io` block, since outside that block it points to the original standard error stream.

```ruby
class T
  def do_something
    log = Logger.new($stderr)
    log.info("Here is an info message")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Documentation of capture_subprocess_io

Basically Leonard's example fleshed out and commented with working code and pointing to the docs.

---

Captures $stdout and $stderr into strings, using Tempfile to ensure that subprocess IO is captured as well.

```
out, err = capture_subprocess_io do
  system "echo Some info"                 # echos to standard out
  system "echo You did a bad thing 1>&2"  # echos to standard error
end

assert_match %r%info%, out
assert_match %r%bad%, err
```

NOTE: This method is approximately 10x slower than #capture_io so only use it when you need to test the output of a subprocess.

[See Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest%2FAssertions%3Acapture_subprocess_io)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but one way we do this is to mock out the logger with an expects. Something like

`logger.expects(:info).with("Here is an info message")`

This allows us to assert the code under test without changing how logger works out of the box.

As an example of `capture_io`, we have a logger implementation to allow us to pass in hashes and output them to json. When we test that implementation we use `capture_io`. This is possible because we initialize the logger implementation in our subject line with `$stdout`.

`subject { CustomLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stdout)) }`

in the test

```
it 'processes a string message' do
  msg = "stuff"
  out, err = capture_io do
    subject.info(msg)
  end
  out.must_equal "#{msg}\n"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Very late but this is a response to an earlier answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27717477/19637807

Building on leveraging StringIO, we can do something like this using minitest and mocha:

```
    log_output_capture = StringIO.new
    logger = Logger.new(log_output_capture)
    Logger.stubs(:new).returns(logger)
```

This ensures that any instantiation of `Logger.new` within the function being invoked for testing will be substituted with the StringIO instance for output. Therefore you don't need to modify the underlying function's logger implementation at all!

I used Jikku's answer to successfully unit test a ruby lambda function by evaluating its expected log output:

```
# after stubbing Logger.new

    lambda_handler(event: @event, context: @context)
    puts log_output_capture.string

    expected_log_output = File.read("expected_outputs/lambda_run.log")
    assert_match(expected_log_output, log_output_capture.string )
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide a different `StringIO` object while initializing `Logger.new` to capture the output, rather than the usual: `STDERR` which actually points to the console.

I modified the above two files a bit and made into a single file so that you can copy and test easily:

```
require 'logger'
require 'minitest'

class T
  def do_something(io = nil)
    io ||= STDERR
    log = Logger.new io
    log.info("Here is an info message")
  end
end

class TestT < Minitest::Test

  def test_something
    t = T.new
    string_io = StringIO.new
    t.do_something string_io
    puts "Out: #{string_io.string}"
  end

end

Minitest.autorun
```

Explanation:

1. Method `do_something` will function normally in all other code when used without the argument.
2. When a `StringIO` method is provided, it uses that instead of the typical `STDERR` thus enabling to capture output like into a file or in this case for testing.

Comment: I don't want to pass a parameter to the do_something function.  I extracted this from a much larger context, and the logger is already configured to either take a file or standard error. I'd have to modify my code as a 'test only' case.  Not really acceptable.

Comment: Sure, I understand your rationale in not modifying the method just for testing it. But I don't think there is a way to redirect console output, anyways please post here know if you find a better way.